# Saving state causes app to crash

Tags: android, savestate

Log is saying activity cant be paused, and a number format exception, I'm trying to save state of two edit texts that hold numbers,but both can be empty or one can be empty

In my activity there are two edit texts the user can either enter numbers manually and move to the next step or open a calculator to add up some numbers, and set the total to one of the edit texts, i want to save the state so if he needs to fill both edit text using the calculator, the first number he set will still be there when they come back with the second number.

I don't know to deal with this, here is the last bit of code i tried.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    double length =Double.parseDouble(edtNumber1.getText().toString());
    double height = Double.parseDouble(edtNumber2.getText().toString());

    outState.putDouble("LENGTH", length);
    outState.putDouble("HEIGHT", height);
}
```

And in onCreate

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    double hght = savedInstanceState.getDouble("LENGTH");
    double lnth = savedInstanceState.getDouble("LENGTH");
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("LENGTH")); {
        edtNumber1.setText(Double.toString(lnth));
    }

    if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("HEIGHT")); {
        edtNumber2.setText(Double.toString(hght)); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` at the end of the method and make sure your editText contain numbers.

Thus, change

`double hght = savedInstanceState.getDouble("LENGTH");`

by

`double hght = savedInstanceState.getDouble("HEIGHT");`

And delete your `;` in `if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("LENGTH"));` and `if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("HEIGHT"));`

Comment: Ok thanks, but see my edit text can both be empty the first time the calculator is opened

Answer (score 1):

IT means that one (or both) of the text fields don't have a number.  You need to catch that exception around ParseDouble and deal with it somehow (probably by using a default).

Comment: Thanks when i give it a default of zero it stops it crashing but it still not saving the state when i navigate away and back, any more suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You have extraneous semi-colons after your "if" statements, turning them into no-ops and causing the blocks that follow to always be executed.

Comment: Also, Gabe Sechan is right; even if the values are found, they could be malformed, causing an exception.